# dlib krr_trainer gives error on multidimensional data

Tags: c++, dlib

I am trying out dlib for a problem. Given the area of house and no of trees in the locality, the price of the house is provided. We wish to predict the price of the house using krr trainer for a given area and no Of Trees

```
area , noOfTrees, priceOFHouse
100 , 10 , 400
100 ,50, 2000
200 , 1,200
.... lots more
```

I planned to use kernel ridge regression

```
typedef matrix<double, 2, 1> sample_type;
typedef radial_basis_kernel<sample_type> kernel_type;
krr_trainer<kernel_type> trainer;

// i took trainign data and put htose data in 2 vectors 
//  std::vector<std::vector<double> > feactureVector;
//  std::vector<double> resultVector;
populateTrainigData(feactureVector, resultVector) ; 
// so featurevector[0] is {100,10} resultvector[0] is 400 
decision_function<kernel_type>  test = trainer.train(feactureVector, resultVector);

sample_type m;
m(0, 0) = 100; // area of house is 100 
m(1, 0) = 25; // no of treess in neighbourhood is 25 

double result = test(m);
```

At line `decision_function<kernel_type>  test` it gives compile error .

```
d:\dlib-19.15\dlib\svm\krr_trainer.h(300): error C2664: 'const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &dlib::empirical_kernel_map<dlib::radial_basis_kernel<sample_type>>::project(const dlib::matrix<T,2,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &,double &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'const dlib::matrix<T,2,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &'
1>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction where I can solve this problem as the example on the dlib site shows only a single dimension example. I am using that as a reference guide and the error & system is strange to me.

Comment: Removed ml tag, which is for the programming language ML.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support doing that.  You should instead call .train() once for each of your outputs.  That is, train separate predictors for each output variable.

Comment: You mean for each line in training set say 1000 lines , we will be calling train method for 1000 times . Sir how will train object ie returned ie decision maker be updated then ? Because my output is just 1 ie cost of house and features are area and no of trees

Comment: I mean use it just like the krr_example program in dlib shows.

Comment: Sir , do you have a link please for above. I was initially referring to http://dlib.net/krr_regression_ex.cpp.html but it has single dimensional.

Comment: That’s the one I’m talking about. Train a single dimension at a time.

Comment: Oh .. sir  , so you means I will have decision_function<kernel_type>  test1 and decision_function<kernel_type>  test2  ; for the 2 features namely area and number of trees . Then I  have 2 results as well  ie  double cost1 =  test1(m1)  and double cost2= test2(m2) ; how will i get the final cost ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you got an error because of this line:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > feactureVector;
```

your features should be a vector of `sample_type` like this:

```
std::vector< sample_type > feactureVector;
```

like in this example: http://dlib.net/krr_regression_ex.cpp.html